# How to add data transformer inside a event listener

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

So, here's my problem: I have to add a field to a form based on it's underlying data but i've to add a data transformer to the field.

I thought the solution will be simple, just add a PRE_SET_DATA event listener to the form (just to access to the underlying data) and add the field and the transformer inside the listener. But i can't add the transformer inside the listener because the form is already locked.

I´ve tried many workarounds but i couldn't solved it. Her's my code:

```
$builder->...
    ->add(
        $builder->create('date', 'choice', array(
            'label' => 'form.game.date',
            'empty_value' => 'form.game.date',
            'required' => false,
            'choices' => array(
                '2014-04-10' => '10/Apr', // just to test
                '2014-04-11' => '11/Apr',
                )
            ))
            ->addModelTransformer(new DateToStringTransformer())
        );

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($builder) {
    $game = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $period = new \DatePeriod(
        $game->getTournament()->getBeginDate(),
        new \DateInterval('P1D'),
        $game->getTournament()->getEndDate()->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'))
    );

    $dates = array();

    foreach($period as $date){
        $dates[$date->format("Y-m-d")] = $date->format("j/M");
    }

    $form->add('date', 'choice', array(
        'label' => 'form.game.date',
        'choices' => $dates,
        ));
});
```

When i add the date field to the form inside event listener, the previously added data field is replaced so it's data transformer...

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some test and updated your code a bit. Check if i understand your question correctly.

SomeTypeTest.php:

```
<?php
class SomeTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function testSubmitValidData()
    {
        $begin = new \DateTime();
        $formData = array(
            'date' => '2014-01-15'
        );

        $type = new SomeType();
        $form = $this->factory->create($type);

        $form->submit($formData);

        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
        $this->assertEquals(['date' => \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2014-01-15')], $form->getData());

        $view = $form->createView();
        $children = $view->children;

        foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
        }
    }
}
```

SomeType.php:

```
<?php
class SomeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($builder) {
                //$game = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $period = new \DatePeriod(
                    \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2014-01-01'), // for test
                    new \DateInterval('P1D'),
                    \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2014-01-30') // for test
                );

                $dates = array();

                foreach ($period as $date) {
                    $dates[$date->format("Y-m-d")] = $date->format("j/M");
                }

                $form->add($builder->create('date', 'choice', array(
                        'label' => 'form.game.date',
                        'empty_value' => 'form.game.date',
                        'auto_initialize' => false,
                        'required' => false,
                        'choices' => $dates
                    ))
                    ->addModelTransformer(new DateToStringTransformer())->getForm()
                );
            });
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'st';
    }
}
```

DateToStringTransformer.php:

```
<?php
class DateToStringTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return mixed|void
     */
    public function transform($value)
    {
        if (!$value) {
            return null;
        }

        return $value->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return mixed|void
     */
    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        return \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value);
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/ChubV/11348928

Comment: Please insert this code in your answer, so it will be self-contained and not just a link.

Comment: I've tried your aproach too and i can't use the builder like that inside the event listener, maybe because i added some fields before calling "$builder->addEventListener" and, in that moment, the form is already locked. I've managed to get it work by creating a custom type that always add the data transformer. Then i can call "form->add('date', 'my_type',..)" from any event listener without loosing the data transformer.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Hm, It works even if i add some fields before an event listener. But your custom type is nice solution too.

Comment: $form->add($builder->create(...)) does't work because "$form->add() needs as param FormInterface|string|int" and "$builder->create return's FormBuilderInterface".

Comment: Look at the post/answer date pls.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it work by creating a custom type that always add the data transformer. Then i can call "form->add('date', 'my_type',..)" from any event listener without loosing the data transformer.

MyType.php

```
class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('field1')
            ->add('field2')
            ...;

        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddDateSubscriber());
    }
}
```

CustomType.php

```
class DateChoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addModelTransformer(new DateToStringTransformer());
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'invalid_message' => 'The selected date does not exist',
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'date_choice';
    }
}
```

Every time i add a date_choice type to a form the data transformer will be added too.

```
class AddDateSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $game = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $endDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $game->getTournament()->getEndDate()->format('Y-m-d'));

        $period = new \DatePeriod(
            $game->getTournament()->getBeginDate(),
            new \DateInterval('P1D'),
            $endDate
        );

        $dates = array();
        foreach($period as $date){
            $dates[$date->format("Y-m-d")] = $date->format("j/M");
        }

        $form->add('date', 'date_choice', array(
            'label' => 'form.game.date.label',
            'empty_value' => 'form.game.date.none',
            'required' => false,
            'choices' => $dates,
            ));
    }
}
```

DateToStringTransformer.php

```
class DateToStringTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($date)
    {
        if (null === $date) {

            return "";
        }

        return $date->format("Y-m-d");
    }

    public function reverseTransform($stringDate)
    {
        if (!$stringDate) {

            return null;
        }

        $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $stringDate);

        if (false === $date) {

            throw new TransformationFailedException('Sting to date transformation failed!');
        }

        return $date;
    }
}
```

Hope that this will help someone.